# How to close .txt file after "exec" use?

Tags: python, exec

I would like to use `exec` in a loop. Is there a need to close files after using `exec`?

My code:

```
f = exec(open("./settings.txt").read())
f.close()
```

Result:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exec'
```

What should I do to close this file?

Comment: typically you don't need to do anything, as python will already call close on the file, as it has no references anywhere.

Comment: Something in my program in the loop terribly ate memory until the PC went into failure. I decided to check everything and doubted whether it was necessary to close the file after "exec" or it's not a problem. Finally solved the issue, there was an endlessly updated and growing list that was not even used. Thanks for the replies guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exec is not a good practise. You can use context manager and your file will be automaticly close:

```
with open("./settings.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

# File is already closed
```

But if you want to use exec you can use:

```
exec('x = open("./settings.txt")')
data = x.read()
x.close()
```